# How to pass in dynamic value into toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, moment-timezone

So I'd like to pass in a dynamic value into toLocaleTimeString. The way the time is formatted is going to change based on the user location. For example time for a user in the UK should be something like 18:00:00, while for someone in America it would be 6:00:00 PM.

The only problem I'm having is doing a dynamic mapping of timezone to which locale to pass in (i.e. "en-GB", "en-US", etc). How do I do this?

I'm using momenttimezone and tzlookup to get the user timezone:

```
let timezone = tzlookup(userLatitude, userLongitude)

var date = new Date()
var localHour = date.toLocaleTimeString("xx-XX") // How do I dynamically set xx-XX to what it's supposed to be based on the user location?
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you use no parameters it should use the timezone and locale from the browser or system.  You shouldn't assume someone's language based on their coordinates.

Comment: @James These times are related to shop open/close times. It's all stored on the backend. At the point I'm at, I don't want to store UTC on the backend and then convert, I'd rather just have the open/close times of shops stored the way they would display on the outside of the shop. I was wondering if there's some kind of mapping from timezone to locale in javascript/NodeJ.

Comment: what about to use this package: [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone)

Answer (score 1):

Time zones and locales are two orthogonal concepts.  You should not make any assumptions that bind them together.  In many cases, they can be quite different.  For example, if I am an English speaking American visiting Japan, my device will likely have a time zone of `Asia/Tokyo` and a locale of `en-US`.

As for `toLocaleTimeString` (and `toLocaleDateString`, `toLocaleString`, `Intl.DateTimeFormat`, etc.) the default value of `undefined` will automatically use the user's current locale.

In other words:

```js
// this uses the current locale and current time zone
date.toLocaleString()

// this uses a specific locale and current time zone
date.toLocaleString('en-US')

// this uses the current locale and a specific time zone
date.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo'})

// this uses a specific locale and a specific time zone
date.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo'})
```

In your example, if you want to display a time in the UK time zone (the mainland, not a dependency or overseas territory), then you can use the time zone `Europe/London`.  Your call to `tzlookup` should be returning that.  You should not choose a locale.  Let the user's browser set that according to their preferences.

```js
const timezone = tzlookup(userLatitude, userLongitude)

const date = new Date()
const localHour = date.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {timeZone: timezone})
```

You should not need moment or moment-timezone for this operation.